# For the View interface in MVP design, how abstract should the IView members be?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, design-patterns

I am still learning MVP.  I have a IView and a presenter.  I have a custom List control that I have written for this application. I'd like to add some items to it, one at a time.  Should I expose IView.AddItem(Item) or should I expose a IView.MyCustomList property?

Is this a matter of style, or is there a *correct* answer to this one?

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe good style will be preserving the MVP pattern's purpose and keeping the code clean.

If I understand correctly, your `CustomList` property would have the type of your custom control. Exposing such property by the view interface would cause all code working with that interface (the presenter) to depend on your control (and to reference it as dependency). This is possible and will probably work fine enough for your requirements, but is against the MVP design pattern. You may want to separate the view implementation and the presenter into different assemblies. But both would have to reference your control. MVP has been designed to separate the user-interface specific interactions and specific control capabilities (which in most cases are framework/vendor dependent) and to hide them from the business logic (the presenter).

In your scenario I'd suggest exposing the `AddItem` method to the presenter - it is the view implementation's responsibility to handle the user controls or any matters related to displaying the data. The presenter on the other hand will concentrate on retrieving the data and doing some business logic.

I suspect you would not have to support different user interface technologies at the same time (Like ASP.NET Web Forms, WPF/Silverligth or ASP.NET MVC) but if you hypothetically have to port an ASP.NET MVC website to a destktop WPF app, and stick to the MVP design pattern, then you would (in the best case) have to only implement the view interface in each UI technology, keeping the same codebase for the presenter, services and all the business logic stuff (Well in reality going from ASP.NET MVC to desktop would be quite an adventure, but the example should emphasize that the presenter and business logic would not have to be modified).

---

PS. Some frameworks in Java have an abstract interfaces (UI models) representing UI components, and can be reused across different UI technologies. In such cases, exposing an UI component via its UI model interface (which it must implement) would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Yea it is totally a matter of style and whatever one you feel more confortable with.

Answer (score 0):

By not exposing your CustomList, you keep more control of HOW an item should be added to your CustomList.
Exposing the AddItem method will protect your list more against possible abuse.

You can choose, it depends on how much control you want to keep over the list.